Can I mix different brands of self leveling concrete?
Like an idiot, I forgot to apply the primer to my floor before mixing a bag of Mapei self leveling compound. I think that once my primer sets, it will be too late to pour the compound. I need two full bags to cover the area I'm leveling, and the closest hardware store only sells Custom... will this set OK with the Mapei?

I have only used one type of self leveling, it required the primer to dry.... I have not looked up what you have yet but, as far as I know this type of stuff usually follow the same guidelines.
